# Making Multi-user Contact Manager with Rails, devise and MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-management-system, devise, mongoid

I'm working on simple **contact manager** that supports **multi-user**. I'm using with `Rails`, `Device`, and `MongoDB` with `MongoID`.

With devise, I easily attached basic login functionality with devise, and used `embedded_in` for attaching contact model to user model.

However, I can't make **user's dashboard page**(and RESTful API endpoint) **that displays user's contact list**. I should make every users' contact list private to each user.

**EDIT** : I followed [RailsApp tutorial](http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-mongoid-devise.html), and this is what I've done so far. I have index page that displays every users' list, and detail view for adding contact data.

The problem is, when user sign up, every user can see everyone's contact. I want to restrict every user should only see their contact list.

And one more thing, I want to unify API endpoint for every user like:

`http://domain.tld/contact.json` for logged in user's contact.

[image: index]

[image: userpage]

Comment: What's the concrete problem? Show us what you have so far.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a real question here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Added my real problem. Thanks for feedback!

Comment: @Xorlev Added my real question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Devise will give you this helper `current_user`. So you can do this in your controller.

```
# dashboard_controller.rb
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index
  @contacts = current_user.contacts
end
```

Then in your view

```
# dashboard/index.html.erb
<% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
<p>
  <strong><%= contact.name %></strong> <br />
  Phone: <%= contact.phone %>
  Mobile: <%= contact.mobile %>
  Email: <%= contact.email %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Is that what you're after?